# Ansible - how ansible_env.PATH is set in SSH session

Tags: python, ansible

I was trying to execute a simple `python --version` command using Ansible, and it was not working no matter how I tried: via `shell` module, via `command` module, via `script` module, via playbook or ad-hoc.

I'm always getting an error:

> unknown option

For example the playbook:

```
---

- name: testing
  hosts: myhost
  sudo: False

  tasks:
       - name: python version
         shell: python --version
```

Then I realized that this is due to the fact how Ansible loads the environment in SSH session. Effectively the error was not coming from the Ansible or command parsing, but from Python version 2.4, that somehow gets in the PATH (`/usr/local/bin`).

Seems like Python 2.4 didn't know the `--version` flag.

The most interesting part is that when I'm performing SSH to the same host as the same user as Ansible does I'm getting `PATH` elements in correct order and the first location where Python exists is the right one with Python 3, while the `/usr/local/bin` is buried deep in the `PATH`.

But when I have added a `which python` task into the playbook I saw that Ansible resolves Python from `/usr/local/bin` and that is the old one (v2.4)

When I execute the `ansible myhost -m setup` I can see that the  `ansible_env.PATH` variable is way shorter then the `PATH` I'm getting by logging in directly.

It would be nice to understand the rules of how this is getting set up.

Exactly the same question was asked here:

> http://grokbase.com/t/gg/ansible-project/1479n0d0qp/ansible-env-path-how-is-it-set

but there was no definite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To get the version of `python` executing your modules and the ansible itself you should use the ansible_fact `ansible_python_version`
- (my home made recommendation) Use full path when using `command` module.

> so the correct answer for me was: in inventory file set the
>   `ansible_python_interpreter=/path/to/correct/python` and then it will be
>   able to use the indicated python when logging to the remote and
>   obviously find it in the PATH.

This is not true. `- shell: python --version` would not use the `ansible_python_interpreter`. It just executes whatever command you give it by looking up the executable (if it's not an absolute path) in PATH.

E.g. if

- you've setup your startup files (`/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `.*rc` etc.) such that python 2.4 is first in `PATH` and
- you set `ansible_python_interpreter` to `/path/to/python3` for my_host

then:

```
- hosts: my_host
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ansible_python_interpreter}}"      # would print /path/to/python3
    - debug: msg="{{ansible_python_version}}"          # would print 3.x
    - shell: python -c 'import sys; print sys.version' # would execute python 2.4
      register: py_version
    - debug: msg="{{py_version}}"                      # would print 2.4
```

What you should be doing is one of the following:

- set PATH correctly. (this is not really an option because "how ansible sets PATH" is undefined see Eugene's comment below)
- use absolute path with `command` module (or `shell` for that matter).

Comment: you're right, ansible_python_interpreter does not resolve the problem of PATH. The confusion is coming from the fact that there is no way to say how the ansible_env.PATH is set, and I'm not the only one confused: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/ansible-project/1479n0d0qp/ansible-env-path-how-is-it-set